# Can I accept all friend requests at once on Foursquare?

Tags: foursquare

On https://foursquare.com/manage/requests, how can I accept all friend requests at once on Foursquare? It is tedious to do it one by one:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not a way. However, if you are a celebrity or other popular person (think Twitter verified), Foursquare can convert your profile to a celebrity account, where the default *friend add* function is to follow, rather than add friend. Source: I am a [Foursquare Superuser 3](http://support.foursquare.com/entries/422546-Superuser-levels-what-they-mean-) and have asked the staff about this.